# Possible generalization of decimal expansion of $\frac{1}{7}$ on an ellipse

Tags: conic-sections, decimal-expansion

My question:
Is there a generalization
of the result below,
either involving more digits
or a fraction other than
$\cfrac{1}{7}$?

The Futility Closet has [this](http://www.futilitycloset.com/2016/06/08/one-seventh-ellipse/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A%20FutilityCloset%20%28Futility%20Closet%29) surprising result:

The One-Seventh Ellipse

The decimal expansion of $\cfrac{1}{7}$ is $0.142857142857\dots$, a repeating decimal. Arrange the six repeating digits into overlapping ordered pairs, like so:
$$
(1, 4), (4, 2), (2, 8), (8, 5), (5, 7), (7, 1),
$$
and, remarkably, all six lie on an ellipse:
$$
19x^2 + 36yx + 41y^2 – 333x – 531y + 1638 = 0.
$$

Even more remarkably, if we take the digits two at a time:
$$
(14, 28), (42, 85), (28, 57), (85, 71), (57, 14), (71, 42),
$$
these points also lie on an ellipse:
$$
-165104x^2 + 160804yx + 8385498x – 41651y^2 – 3836349y – 7999600 = 0
$$

That’s from David Wells, The Penguin Dictionary of Curious and Interesting Numbers (1986). Victor Hugo wrote, “Mankind is not a circle with a single center but an ellipse with two focal points, of which facts are one and ideas the other.”

Comment: Have you tried $1/17$, the next full period fraction?

Comment: I suspect that this works for any prime $p$ so long as you write it in a base $b$ where the decimal expansion of $\frac{1}{p}$ is repeating with period $p-1$ (aka, $p$ is a full reptend prime in base $b$). You probably also need that $b>p$.

Comment: Many details here: http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/EMAT6680Fa07/Gleason/Maple/Maple.html It turns out to not be that rare of a property.

Comment: Turning Nick William's answer into a comment: Here's a relatively recent paper on precisely your question: Marc Chamberland, Shida Jing & Sanah Suri (2020) A Generalization of the One-Seventh Ellipse, https://doi.org/10.1080/0025570X.2020.1794198.

Comment: @TobyMak: The paper (or perhaps version of it) is available directly from Chamberland [here (PDF link via grinnell.edu)](https://chamberland.math.grinnell.edu/papers/one-seventh.pdf).